# Data only displayed after refresh

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I am creating comments section in my app, when a user enter a comments and submit, comment should imeaditely be displayed in front end, unfortunately now comments are only visible after refresh,

Here is what I have :

> Displaying comments

component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
       this.activeRouter.params.subscribe((params) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
      let id = params['id'];
      this.moviesService.getComments(id)
        .subscribe(comments => {
          console.log(comments);
          this.comments = comments;
        });
    });
}
```

service.ts

```
 getComments(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${apiUrl + this.commentsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments" class="col-md-7">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Author: {{comment.author}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Comments: {{comment.description}}</li>
          </ul>
          <br>
        </div>
```

**

> Adding comments:

**
service.ts

```
  // Adds comments
      addReview(author, description) {
        const uri = 'http://localhost:8000/movies/comments';
        const obj = {
          author: author,
          description: description
        };
        return this.http.post(uri, obj);
      }
```

compo.ts

```
  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      author: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  addReview(author, description) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description).subscribe(success => {
      this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
    }, error => {
      this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-7 movie-form" >
          <flash-messages></flash-messages>
          <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4">Author</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" formControlName="author" #author />
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['author'].invalid && (angForm.controls['author'].dirty || angForm.controls['author'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['author'].errors.required">
                Name is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4">Description</label>
              <textarea cols="10" rows="10" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="description" #description>
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['description'].invalid && (angForm.controls['description'].dirty || angForm.controls['description'].touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['description'].errors.required">
                description is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button (click)="addReview(author.value, description.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

***Question***

what is wrog with my code? any help suggestion will be apreciated

Comment: I think you should  call getComments  after adding of new one for updating  comments list

Comment: You don't actually show how you create the new comment - does that trigger a new fetch? It won't magically make another GET request just because you know there's new data now; *Angular* doesn't know that.

Comment: what do umean? can you be more specific? am new to all this stuff

Comment: Please provide  method which create  comment

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr updated the qn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your `getComments` method in the callback of you submit comments. Your code only has a "get" call in `ngOnInit` method of the component. So when you refresh your view, the `ngOnInit` executes again and thus `getComments` is called.

You have to make a get call in the callback of your submit comments method.

EDIT#1:

```
addReview(author, description) {
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description).subscribe(success => {
        this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
        // get the id
        this.moviesService.getComments(id).subscribe(comments => {
            console.log(comments);
            this.comments = comments;
        });
    }, error => {
        this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
}
```

Comment: You have to make a get call in the callback of your submit comments method. what exactly do u mean ? am learning , can you show me example?

Comment: can you explain what did you mean ? You have to make a get call in the callback of your submit comments method.

Answer (score 3):

@Kaczkapojebana. When we subscribe to a "get", DON'T mean that a change in the dbs was displayed in the view. (only say that when the asyncronous called is completed, the data is showed). I usually refered to "get" subscription as "subscription of only one use".

You must add manually to this.comments the new data. where? IN subscribe function:

```
addReview(author, description) { 
    this.moviesService.addReview(author, description).subscribe(success => {  
      /***add manually to this.comments***********/
      this.comments.push({author:author,descripcion:description});

      this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
    }, error => {
      this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
  }
```

NOTE: You can also subscribe again to get all the data or that the addReview response all the data
NOTE2: Equally, when you make an update, you must update the "this.comments" array manually