# The new record created is only displayed after the page is reloaded

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a modal window with a form to create new records. It should work like this: after clicking on the create modal button, the window should close immediately, a new created record will appear in the table and a message should appear on the right that the record was successfully created. But at the moment the only thing that works correctly is only closing the modal window, to see the new record you need to refresh the page, and the message about the created record is not displayed at all.

How can this be fixed?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogRef, ModalComponent } from 'angular2-modal';
import { Post } from '../../../../../models/post.model';
import { PostService} from '../../../../../services/post/post.service';
import { BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { ToastsManager } from "ng2-toastr";
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-post',
  templateUrl: './add-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-post.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
})

export class AddPostComponent  implements OnInit, ModalComponent<any> {

  post = new Post;
  posts: Array<Post>;

  constructor(
    public dialog: DialogRef<any>,
    public authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private servPost: Post,
    public toastManager: ToastsManager,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef
  ) { 
    toastManager.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



savePost() {
  this.servPost.createPost(this.post).subscribe
    (success => {
        this.toastManager.success('Data successfully created!', 'Done');
        this.servPost.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
          console.log(posts);
          this.posts = posts;
        });


    }, error => {
      this.toastManager.error(getErrorTextFromJSON(error.json()), 'Error');
    });

    this.dialog.close(null); 

 }

}
```

Сan somehow add page refresh options after creating a new record? At the very least, a person will not need to update the page himself to display a new record.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032054/data-only-displayed-after-refresh/51036316#51036316

Comment: @Eliseo Did not help, updated the question code

Comment: Please, show the code of your HTML-Template.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question so quickly. Check the response of createPost (even you can put the this.dialog.close(null) inside subscribe function od getPost

Answer (score 0):

if createPost is returning the newly created entity, then you can :

```
savePost() {
  this.servPost.createPost(this.post).subscribe(
     data => {

        this.toastManager.success('Data successfully created!', 'Done');

        // check returned data from rest service
        console.log(data);

        // add the returned data from rest service into posts array
        this.posts.push( data );

        this.dialog.close(null);

     }, 
     error => {
        this.toastManager.error(getErrorTextFromJSON(error.json()), 'Error');
     }
  );

}
```