# How to bind angular 2 dropdown dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown like shown below

```
<select  id="usersList" style="width:200px" (change)="onUserChange($event)">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select a User</option>
 <option *ngFor="let item of users" [value]="item.sid">{{item.lastName +', '+ item.firstName}}</option>
</select>
```

After selecting any value from the dropdown, I am deleting that value, Afer deletion how can I refresh the drop-down values again.

Comment: are you calling a service to populate this dropdown data?

Comment: Yes, I am calling a service to populate this dropdown once this component gets initialized.

Comment: why do you want to refresh the drop-down values again  ??

Comment: can you post your delete function here!

Comment: delete(){
    
      
      this.us.DeleteUser(user).subscribe(
        (data) => {          
            this.users.push(data)    ;
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log("Add error", err)
        }
    );
This is the delete function

Comment: If i don't refresh the drop-down, after deletion of value it will try again to bind that value which is already deleted, and its giving me error.

Comment: if you want to refresh the dropdown, you can call the service you have used to populate it and have it assign to the users variable.

Comment: @user3615760, the problem is that when you delete an user, your variable "users" go on maintancee the same value. A subscription of a http.get not "main" that what-ever dbs happens you get the new values. You must or call the subscription again or delete manually the element of the array, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032054/data-only-displayed-after-refresh/51036316#51036316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after successful deletion, you should call the same function which is giving you the drop-down output I hope you will get updated data after deletion of your one value.

```
delete() {
        this.us.DeleteUser(user).subscribe((data) => { this.yourfunction_to_call_dropdowndata();
}, (err) => { console.log("Add error", err) });
    }
```